# How to use ctypes to call 'AU3_WinGetTitle' in AutoIt?

Tags: python, ctypes, autoit

I'm trying to make a python wrapper for AutoIt using ctypes.

Here is my problem:

e.g. The prototype for AU3_WinGetText is:

`void AU3_WinGetTitle(LPCWSTR szTitle, LPCWSTR szText, LPWSTR szRetText, int nBufSize);`

I'm using flowing code to call the function:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import *

AUTOIT = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("AutoItX3.dll")


def win_get_title(title, text="", buf_size=200):
    AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle.argtypes = (LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LPWSTR, INT)
    AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle.restypes = None
    rec_text = LPWSTR()
    AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle(LPCWSTR(title), LPCWSTR(text),
                          ctypes.cast(ctypes.byref(rec_text), LPWSTR),
                          INT(buf_size))
    res = rec_text.value
    return res

print win_get_title("[CLASS:Notepad]")
```

I'm getting an exception after run these codes:

```
    res = rec_text.value
ValueError: invalid string pointer 0x680765E0
```

Comment: Do you need the `cast`? What happens if the 3rd argument is just `rec_text` (or `ctypes.byref(rec_text)`)?

Comment: Go you! Now, to help others do the same you should post your solution in an answer and mark it answered by yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

`szRetText` is used to receive the output text buffer

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import *

AUTOIT = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("AutoItX3.dll")


def win_get_title(title, text="", buf_size=200):
    # AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle.argtypes = (LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LPWSTR, INT)
    # AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle.restypes = None
    rec_text = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(buf_size)
    AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle(LPCWSTR(title), LPCWSTR(text),
                          rec_text, INT(buf_size))
    res = rec_text.value.rstrip()
    return res

print win_get_title("[CLASS:Notepad]")
```

Comment: Simpler DLL load: `AUTOIT = ctypes.WinDLL('AutoItX3')`. Windows appends ".dll" to the library name. For efficiency, define `argtypes` and `restype` (not plural `restypes`) only once, i.e. not in the function: `AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle.restype = None; AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle.argtypes = (wintypes.LPCWSTR, wintypes.LPCWSTR, wintypes.LPWSTR, wintypes.INT)`. Another way to create the out buffer: `rec_text = (ctypes.c_wchar * buf_size)()`. With `argtypes` the call is simply `AUTOIT.AU3_WinGetTitle(title, text, rec_text, buf_size)`.

Comment: Hey that was my answer ;)